# keyboad layout after change with command setxkbmap -model not working in ubuntu apps

Tags: keyboard, thinkpad

I am using the command `setxkbmap -model abnt2 -layout br -variant abnt2` and it is changing the keyboard to the brazilian format. However it is not saving the changes and is not being accepted within the system in the browser.

Then every time I restart the system I need to do this command again to format the layout again.

In addition, I have a key with the interrogation and forward slash that is not being accepted in any language.

What should I do.

Comment: Do you need this format to be used for only yourself or are their multiple users on the system?

Comment: It is just for myself.

Comment: Thank you for providing that information. Please see my answer. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the command you provided is working for you and you are simply trying to avoid entering it every time you start the system or login.
Fortunately getting commands to run at startup and login are relatively simple. Credit where credit is due: My answer is inspired by [This one on our sister site unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/99090)

If it's ok to run this command for every user on the system just place the line at the bottom of /etc/profile. A command like the below should do that.

```
echo setxkbmap -model abnt2 -layout br -variant abnt2 >>/etc/profile
```

To have it only effect your user account instead use

```
echo setxkbmap -model abnt2 -layout br -variant abnt2 >> $HOME/.profile
```